# How to add popup on close a browser tag ,inside a popup show img,when we clik this ,it hide and show a div message

Tags: php, html

i want to two  popup show when close a browser tag of site
1.leave and stay confirmation.and
2. for showing a image inside this ,when we click on this ,it hide and show a warning message on top of header,like this http://eyetensive.com/aa/

Pls help soon

Comment: try this <body onunload="myFunction()"> edit myFunction in java script

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind to the window unload and show your modal.

Lets say this is the html you want to show called "showme" which is hidden with `hide` class then the following will show the html and show the alert message when the user attempts to leave.

```
<div id="showme" class="hide">
 <h1>I am now shown!</h1>
</div>

<style>.hide {display:none}</style>

<script>
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    document.getElementById("showme").className = ""; // remove class
    return 'Do you want leave.'; // firefox shows custom text that can't be changed
};
</script>
```

Comment: thanks,but how to show second popup for image showing?

Comment: @naren - i have updated my answer to show how using a class can show the hidden element.